# Location-based marketing - Providing ticketing and access to attractions. (Smart Destinations) - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, mobile, us20120323691

**AN OVERBROAD PATENT ON Enhanced marketing responsive to customer path data between attractions** - This application from [Smart Destinations, Inc](http://www.smartdestinations.com/) seeks to patent the idea of...Enhanced data collection and reporting for improved ticket pricing and marketing. 10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

**QUESTION** - Have you seen anything that was **published before 6/15/2011** that discusses:

> - Enhanced data collection related to a customer's travel path in order to improve ticket pricing and marketing

If so, please submit evidence of prior art as an answer to this question. We welcome multiple answers from the same individual.

**EXTRA CREDIT** - Dynamically pricing and validating access to goods, services, attractions, events and other items

**TITLE: Method for enhanced marketing responsive to customer path data between attractions**

**Summary**:  [Translated from Legalese into English] Receiving an identification of a location of a user and a **first attraction** selected for access by a user, determining a **travel path** between the location of the user and the **first attraction**, identifying a **second attraction** within a predetermined distance from the **travel path**, and transmitting an offer of access to the **second attraction** to a computing device of the user.

- **Publication Number**: [US 20120323691 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120323691)
- **Application Number**: US 13/523,213
- **Assignee**: [Smart Destinations, Inc.](http://www.smartdestinations.com/)
- **Prior Art Date**: Seeking prior Art **predating** 6/15/2011
- **Link to Google Prior Art Search** - ["Find Prior Art"](https://www.google.com/patents/related/US20120323691)

**Claim 1** requires each and every step below:

> A method for enhanced marketing responsive to customer path data between attractions, comprising:
>
> 1. Receiving, by a first device, an identification of a location of a user and a first attraction selected for access by a user;
> 2. Determining, by a path analyzer, a travel path between the location of the user and the first attraction;
> 3. Identifying, by the path analyzer, a second attraction within a predetermined distance from the travel path; and
> 4. Transmitting, by the first device to a computing device of the user, an offer of access to the second attraction.

In English this means:

> A method for better customer marketing based on customer path data between attractions
>
> 1. Receive an identification of a user's location and a first attraction selected for access by the user;
> 2. Determine a travel path between the location of the user and the first attraction;
> 3. Identify a second attraction within a predetermined distance from the travel path; and
> 4. Transmit an offer of access to the second attraction to a computing device of the user.

Good prior art would be evidence of a system that did each and every one of these steps prior to 6/15/2011

You're probably aware of ten pieces of art that meet this criteria already... separately, the applicant is claiming Identifying the second attraction based on a net price. The  net price being below a net price threshold or an average customer visit time of the second attraction being above a visit time threshold.

---

**"Location-based marketing for attraction access" from the Applicant**

[image]

---

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

---

Comment: We may want to update this to the issued patent US9858537. The claims have changed somewhat from the application's. https://patents.google.com/patent/US9858537B2/en

Answer (score 0):

This appear to be an obvious, the what's around feature present in many GPS enabled devices does almost the same thing. Its an obvious refinement to display offers in this case.

An example would be clicking what food outlet is nearby and providing coupons to the device for nearby restaurants.

Comment: Only finding an example predating 6/16/2011 represents prior art.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are many other inventions similar to the present invention, but for the time being we will introduce the following prior art.

Date of publication of application：14.10.2010
Application number：2009-075056(JP) 
[0027] 
 The introductory information transmission section 222 transmits the introductory information held at the information holding part 212 to the mobile terminal 150 through the server communications department 210 based on the acquisition request of the terminal position information and introductory information which were transmitted from the mobile terminal 150. In this embodiment, the introductory information which the introductory information transmission section 222 transmits is the introductory information of the object which exists in the prescribed range on the basis of the position which terminal position information shows. This terminal position information is information transmitted from the mobile terminal 150, and shows the present position of this mobile terminal 150. Here, although the introductory information transmission section 222 transmits the introductory information of the object which exists in the prescribed range on the basis of the position of the mobile terminal 150 which terminal position information shows, it can also transmit all the introductory information related to the map information concerned held at the information holding part 212.

Comment: This could be a useful answer. Two improvements perhaps. First if there is an actual publication, please link to it. Second, try to improve the formatting as it is hard to follow as it is now. The editor has some tools to improve this. Try the quoting tool.

Answer (score 0):

Does Priceline, Hotwire and other similar bid systems compare - esp. for Hotels? Offers are based upon location and the system shows offers nearby. I have used it to make last minute hotel bookings on last minute business travel relying on their system to find best price and nearest location.